# Bounded mismatch in Eclipse. "The type is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter"

Tags: java, generics

I have a generic class, Storage, and another generic class, StoragePlus. I'm getting a bounded error mismatch error for the lines with comments in bold below.

Here's my code for the first class.

```
public class Storage<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {
//private T t;
private T[] isafe;
public int max;
private int nextIndex;

public Storage(int maxNum, T[] seedArr){

    if(maxNum < 0){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    else{

        isafe = Arrays.copyOf(seedArr, maxNum);
        nextIndex = 0;
        max = maxNum;

    }
}
```

and here's the code for the second class.

```
public class StoragePlus <T> extends Storage<T>{ **//getting an error here**

public StoragePlus(int maxNum, T[] arr){
    super(maxNum,(Comparable[]) arr);
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj){
    if(obj == null|| obj.getClass() != this.getClass()){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        if(obj == this){
            return true;    
        }
        else{
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Storage<?> temp = (Storage<T>) obj; **// also getting an error here**
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want

```
Storage<T extends Comparable<T>>
StoragePlus<T extends Comparable<T>> extends Storage<T>
```

And in equals you will only be able to cast `Object` to `Storage<?>`. Otherwise, you need `@SuppressWarnings`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're not restricting the `T` for `StoragePlus`.